# Mode 01 PID 01 OBD-II

Tags: obd-ii, hyundai, dtc, obd, skoda

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBD-II_PIDs#Mode_1_PID_01

Mode 01 PID 01 - Monitor status since DTCs cleared.

In the 1st chart, B7 is 'Reserved' and must be 0.  But for a few cars (like Skoda Rapid) strangely B7 came as 1. Why should that happen if the bit is reserved to be 0?

Answer (score 1):

B7 is a code reserved for manufacturers so they can test for their own custom failures. They could be silly and use it to test if your dashboard light is burnt out for example.

Default, as in the generic OBD2 spec, it should be 0.

Ultimately a 1 in some cars could be normal, but who knows. People need to look up the specific code for that specific model to find out.

here is a guide to decoding obd2 codes. B7 will be the second X.

[image: here is a guide to decoding obd2 codes]

From what I can gather it looks like it can display up to a 4 bit digit. and it looks like B3 is the test ready flag for the B7 output.